# Rendering issue on iPad display of website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ipad, webkit

I have encountered the strangest problem I have ever encountered in my web development career, and I just cannot seem to solve it.

I developed a website: www.ktngroup.co.uk a few months back, all worked perfectly upon launch across all devices. Now it would seem as though the site has developed some form of issue limited only to ipad. The strange thing is, I cannot replicate it when using css user agents and screen sizes, which is strange becuase it looks like a css problem.

I cannot describe the issue very well, but it looks as though all the content (Except the header) is pulled off the site on ipad/not displayed. Also, when using adobe edge inspect; I see that none of my css rules are being applied to the elements.

Comparing the desktop version at 1024px vs the ipad landscape is the best way to discover the issue.

UPDATE: When I cancel the iPad fully loading the site (roughly the first two panels) the site functions perfects on those two panels – almost as if its loading something further down that breaks the site?

If anyone has any guidance, I truly could not thank you enough.

Comment: That's the least of your concerns.  I almost had a seizure clicking on a link in chrome, the page would rapidly pulsate up and down a few times before scrolling to the proper area.  My hunch is that jQuery scroll is misbehaving.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you testing? I'm noticing some weirdness in iOS 7. For me, it looks as if the height of the section elements (`.main_section`) are having some wonky calculated heights (insanely huge) causing the sliding images to expand wildly. Each slide transition causes a terrible paint time. If I change the height from `100vh` to `768px`, things look better. Are we talking about the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may encounter the issue – it's what Jack Pattishall suggested. The iPad didn't seem to respect vh as a unit, and as a result my images were huge.

To fix this I added a media query to handle the handheld tablets with a set pixel width/height.

Hopefully this can be of use to someone